# How can I get a variable from the class and use it in other .py file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, class

I want to get `msg` from the `class Admin`, `def message()`, and then use it in other .py file.

I tried to use `global` everywhere and tried to use `Admin().message()` to get `msg`, but it doesn't work.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys
import admin

class Admin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, admin.Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Admin, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.send_button.clicked.connect(self.message)

    def message(self):
        name = self.name.text()
        price = self.price.text()
        desc = self.description.text()
        msg = f'{name}, {price}, {desc}'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    a = Admin()
    a.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Replace `msg = ...` by `self.msg = ...` and then you can use `a.msg`.

Comment: What's the name of the module containing `class Admin`?

Comment: Or replace `msg = ...` by `return ...` and then you can use `msg = a.message()`.